# Sharepoint portal 2007 view modified date

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using MS Sharepoint portal 2007. I have created views from the data already existed. I need the users to update everyday the status. Any way I know if they have updated like can I get a date modified column or row?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your question right, then you want to get the ROw modified date in your view? Correct me if i am wrong?

If that is your requirement then you have to modify that view and select the column named as "Modified" and If you want to have the user name then also select "Modified By" column.

let me know the result.

Thanks